Cannot map in TypeScript
I am currently following a tutorial and I am stuck in front of this error:
TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<WorkerData, WorkerData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, WorkerData>'.
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'WorkerData': items, meta, links
WorkerData is a simple interface located in the same file:
export interface WorkerData {
  items: Worker[],
  meta: {
    totalItems: number;
    itemCount: number;
    itemsPerPage: number;
    totalPages: number;
    currentPage: number;
  }, 
  links: {
    first: string;
    previous: string;
    next: string;
    last: string;
  }
};

the function that returns this error is this:
findAll(page: number, size: number): Observable<WorkerData> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('page', String(page));
    params = params.append('limit', String(size));
    return this.http.get('/api/worker', {params}).pipe(
      map((userData: WorkerData) => userData),
      catchError(err => throwError(err)),
    )
  }

This func. supposed to return JSON with an array of Worker and some meta. If I change map((userData: WorkerData) => userData) to map((userData: any) => userData), r if I make all params in the interface not meccecary, it works but it returns something like this:
_Observable {
  source: _Observable {
    source: _Observable {
      source: [_Observable],
      operator: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    operator: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  operator: [Function (anonymous)]
}

If anyone is curious the tutorial series are called Blog Project V-09. Maybe this helpsIf you need any more info I will be glad ti give it. Also I can publish this to git if needed. Thanks in advance

Not an answer, but why even use map there? You're just mapping the data to itself. Try this.http.get<WorkerData>('/api/worker', {params}).pipe( instead though

You don't show the type of Worker in the items array but unless it's the built-in type for Web Workers do not give your types the same name as built in types. Beyond that, data that is fetched over the wire at runtime cannot have a shape that is known at compile-time. You are assuming the endpoint is returning JSON with that shape.

The default http.get method does not know what type is returned, so try the following code, this is based on the official Angular documentation
return this.http.get<WorkerData>('/api/worker', { params }).pipe(
  map((userData: WorkerData) => userData),
  catchError(err => throwError(err)),
);

Angular documentation

That is questionable advice. From the very documentation you linked: "Specifying the response type is a declaration to TypeScript that it should treat your response as being of the given type. This is a build-time check and doesn't guarantee that the server actually responds with an object of this type. It is up to the server to ensure that the type specified by the server API is returned." There's no guarantee the response has that shape and OP should check rather than just assume.

I agree wih Jared, if you have a robust design, it sholdn't be a problem, and this is the very point of TypeScript.
